# Haskell: GADT with UNPACK Pragma

Tags: haskell, ghc, pragma, unpack, gadt

UNPACK supports normal data types, as shown in the following:

```
data T = T {-# UNPACK #-} ! Int
```

But is there a way to use the UNPACK Pragma with GADT?

Answer (score 9):

Tried it and found that it actually works with Constructor function arguments.

```
data BinHeap a where
  Empty :: (Ord a) => BinHeap a
  HeapNode :: (Ord a) => a -> {-# UNPACK #-} !Int -> BinHeap a -> BinHeap a -> BinHeap a
```

Nice.